# How do I make Prometheus scrape metrics with POST?

Tags: http-post, prometheus

I have a datasource that I can access remotely with a POST request (including an API key and user ID as data in the request).

Is there anyway to configure Prometheus to scrape this datasource? Preferably without any additional software.

Comment: Have you found any answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, prometheus only supports the GET method.

And you can auth with basic_auth or bearer token.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config